# Problem with NIntegrate over a highly-oscillatory integrand

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I'm trying to numerically evaluate the integral $$\int_{a}^{b}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{x}^{b}\frac{\sin(x-y)}{xy}\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}$$
using Mathematica. To do that, I the function

```
Si2[a_, b_] := NIntegrate[Sin[x - y]/(x y), {x, a, b}, {y, x, b},
  AccuracyGoal -> 25, PrecisionGoal -> 25, WorkingPrecision -> 40,
  MaxRecursion -> 1000000, Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"];
```

However, running `Si2[.1,1]` gives the error

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Sin[x-y]/(x y) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1},{0,1}}.

However, I'm not integrating over $x=y=0$ (which is an obvious singularity).

Two notes:

1. This is an example of usage. In practice, I need to evaluate this function for parameters much closer to $a=0$ (e.g. $\log_{10}(a)\sim-6$).
2. Note that I use the `InterpolationPointsSubdivision` method because I saw in various answers that it is a good method to evaluate numerically a highly-oscillatory integrand. I tried to use few other methods, but got the same error.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: `InterpolationPointsSubdivision` is only intended for integrands that involve an `InterpolatingFunction` object, so no surprise that it failed here.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Your'e correct but it's not an issue - specifying `Method->"OscillatorySelection"`, for example, returns the same error.

Comment: The inner integral should be expressible in terms of the sine and cosine integrals, so that you are left with a 1D integral. Have you tried it?

Comment: No, but I'll try.

Comment: I only have *gedanken Mathematica*, so please try `With[{a = 1*^-6, b = 1}, NIntegrate[(CosIntegral[b] - CosIntegral[x]) Sinc[x] - Cos[x] (SinIntegral[b] - SinIntegral[x])/x, {x, a, b}]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that?

```
Si2[a_, b_] := 
 NIntegrate[Sin[x - y]/(x y), {x, a, b}, {y, x, b}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 25, PrecisionGoal -> 25, WorkingPrecision -> 40, 
   MaxRecursion -> 100000000, {Method -> "QuasiMonteCarlo"}] // Quiet
Si2[0.1, 1]
```

The result is

-0.7030662536921237781417087351943610040114

and it's not very slow

```
In[65]:= % // AbsoluteTiming

Out[65]= {0.007766, -0.7030662536921237781417087351943610040114}
```

so you can try to increase maxrecursion, etc etc

Comment: It is even faster than the automatic method.

Comment: It gives an error, but yes it is and this is why I posted it. Every method I tried gives a similar result, but this is the fastest I found and one can go crazy with accuracy etc etc

Comment: @EZSlaver The answer is fast, but the accuracy is very bad, only about 4 digits of precision are correct. Strange that this is the accepted answer when the OP requested 25 digits of precision.

Comment: Maybe the OP wanted a bad answer quickly, which is admittedly easy to do. ;)

Comment: I never said that my answer is the precise one, I just made a suggestion as some sort of a starting point and maybe one could build from there. And that was before I saw @J.M.iscomputer-less comment.

Answer (score 4):

Here is @JM's answer. First integrate the interior integral:

```
i1[a_, b_] = Integrate[Sin[x-y]/y, {y, x, b}, Assumptions -> 0<x<b]
```

> (CosIntegral[b] - CosIntegral[x]) Sin[x] + 
>    Cos[x] (-SinIntegral[b] + SinIntegral[x])

Then, use this integral:

```
int[a_, b_, opts:OptionsPattern[NIntegrate]] := NIntegrate[i1[a, b]/x, {x, a, b}, opts]
```

Reproducing previous results:

```
int[.1, 1, WorkingPrecision->40] //AbsoluteTiming
int[10^-6, 1, WorkingPrecision->40] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.413422, -0.7031515701355189970289164059287652664106}
>
> {0.882268, -11.18694435428611911727667338594134335609}

Answer (score 3):

Why such a high accuracy? You can simply calculate the integral without options

```
i2[a_, b_] := 
     NIntegrate[NIntegrate[Sin[x - y]/(x y), {y, x, b}], {x, a, b}] // 
       Quiet // AbsoluteTiming


 i2[1/10, 1]

Out[]= {0.697864, -0.703152}
```

Comment: I need high accuracy because the integrand is very oscillatory, and as I've said, I need it down to very values of `a` (and of `b` as well)

Comment: There are no oscillations, I calculated in 1 second `In[7]:= i2[10^-6, 1] Out[7]= {1.33688, -11.1869}`